# How to create an empty blue colour image?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to create an empty blue image using opencv and python. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Please read [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to ask a minimal, reproducible example. You need to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to create an empty blue color image:

```
blue_image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
blue_image[:,:] = (255, 0, 0)
```